# HttpLibrary.HTTP Library No keyword with name 'Get Json Value' found

Tags: robotframework

Trying to learn json operations with RobotFramework. Installed HttpLibrary using "*pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org robotframework-httplibrary*"
From help doc i copied below code and ran to see "***No keyword with name 'Get Json Value' found.***
"
My program

```
*** Settings ***
Library           HttpLibrary.HTTP
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Read_Json
    ${result}=  Get Json Value  {"foo": {"bar": [1,2,3]}}   /foo/bar
    Should Be Equal ${result}   [1, 2, 3]
```

Any help Why is RobotFramework behaving like this?

FYI I am having python 3.6.4

Comment: Are you certain that the import of the library is working? When I try to run the code in your question with python3  I get an error when trying to import the library. It appears that this library can't be used with python3 without a modification.

Comment: I did import using the line which i gave in Question. after install i did small change..   except ValueError, e:   TO except ValueError as e:

Comment: When I fix that line, there's another, and when I fix that there's another error. This code doesn't seem to support python 3

Comment: true MAX i did two fixes. with similar type.

Comment: @BryanOakley  any issues reported or any recent fixes around this problem?

Comment: @Dev: I have no idea. Go to the project repository and you can look for yourself.

Comment: @BryanOakley I found it  [here](https://github.com/peritus/robotframework-httplibrary/issues/57), and it seems that httplibrary is not updated since last 5+ years, I would love to contribute, but i don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

there is no 4 time space(tab button on keyboard) between keyword and variables, before and after keyword, notice the spaces as in below code snip.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           HttpLibrary.HTTP
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Read_Json
${result}=    Get Json Value    {"foo": {"bar": [1,2,3]}}   /foo/bar
Should Be Equal    ${result}    [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: No Dev its not the case. I am sure of the spaces. However i did wat you said. Getting same error.

Comment: You are correct about the spaces on the `should be equal` statement, but the rest of the answer is incorrect. The code in the question has an appropriate number of spaces on the line with `Get Json Value`.

Comment: yes @Bryan you are correct, I had tried that code with `python 2.7.8` and `robotframework-httplibrary==0.4.2` and it works fine